# How to enable spellchecking in WebStorm for YAML content

Tags: yaml, webstorm, spell-checking

I am using WebStorm and have some YAML files within my project. Somehow WebStorm's spellchecker only works for text in quotes within this YAML file. But I would really like that it checks everything in this YAML files.

Is it some of my settings that are wrong or is this the default behaviour of WebStorm? I am using the YAML plugin, maybe this is the reason?

Answer (score 2):

It's not yet supported, please vote for [IDEA-212852](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212852) to be notified on any progress with it